# ¿Cómo traduzco ese src de css para que lo reconozca spring?

Tags: html, css, spring

Estoy intentando implementar unos íconos para el menú de la página web, el código css es:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src:  url('fonts/icomoon.eot?idm0oi');
  src:  url('fonts/icomoon.eot?idm0oi#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.ttf?idm0oi') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.woff?idm0oi') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.svg?idm0oi#icomoon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

¿Cómo puedo traducir los src para que spring los reconozca? Ya que no reconoce la forma en la que lo estoy llamando y no muestra ningún ícono, sólo los cuadros de cuando no se reconoce el ícono

Comment: Los cuadradillos podrían aparecer porque no se estén cargando las fuentes correctamente. ¿Cuál es la estructura de tu proyecto? (en particular el fichero donde está este css y los ficheros de las fuentes) ¿y si abres la consola de errores ves algún error?

Answer (score 0):

Si estás usando [IcoMoon](https://icomoon.io/) para ver los íconos deberías usar los caracteres **unicode**. Por ejemplo:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  src:  url('fonts/icomoon.eot?idm0oi');
  src:  url('fonts/icomoon.eot?idm0oi#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.ttf?idm0oi') format('truetype'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.woff?idm0oi') format('woff'),
    url('fonts/icomoon.svg?idm0oi#icomoon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

.icomoon {
  font-family: icomoon;
}

.icon-user:before {
  content: "\e971"; /* es la manera de escribir en unicode en css */
}
```

Y en el html:

```
<h3>
  <span class="icomoon icon-user"></span>
  Usuario
</h3>
```

Y si lo querés usar en un html, de la siguiente manera:

```
<!-- &#xe971; es el unicode para la versión en html-->
<h3>&#xe971; Usuario</h3>
```

---

**Nota**: el unicode que utilicé fue un ejemplo, vos lo vas a tener que ver una vez que generás la fuente.